# WebException.Response.GetResponseStream() limited to 65536 characters

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I am trying to retrieve HTML code from a webpage using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
...
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

The response object has a ContentLength value of 106142. When I look at the stream object, it has a length of 65536. When reading the stream with a StreamReader using ReadToEnd(), only the first 65536 characters are returned.

How can I get the whole code?

**Edit:**

Using the following code segment:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    errorMessage = errorMessage + ex.Message;
    if (ex.Response != null) {
        if (ex.Response.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            using (Stream stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string pageOutput = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

ex.Response.ContentLength = **106142**

ex.Response.GetResponseStream().Length = **65536**

stream.Length = **65536**

pageOutput.Length = **65534** (because of the trim)

And yes, the code is actually truncated.

Comment: Have you looked at the result string?  Does it look like there is something missing?  Depending on the encoding used, ContentLength (in bytes) might not match the # of characters returned from ReadToEnd() (i.e. if it's using two bytes per char, etc.)

Comment: thanks for posting the actual problem. So, the problem is that the response body from a WebException is truncated.

Comment: @John: Yes, I agree my question could have been more clear.

Comment: For future visitors: To actually resolve this issue rather than hope it doesn't happen to you; please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918107/system-net-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream-returns-truncated-body-in-webexce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem when calling the GetResponseStream() method on the HttpWebResponse returned by the exception. Everything works as expected when there is no exception.

I wanted to get the HTML code from the error returned by the server.

I guess I'll have to hope the error doesn't exceed 65536 characters...

Answer (score 7):

You can find an answer in this topic in [System.Net.HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() returns truncated body in WebException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918107/system-net-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream-returns-truncated-body-in-webexce)

You have to manage the `HttpWebRequest` object and change `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` property.
For example :

```
HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength = 1048576;
```

Answer (score 1):

ReadToEnd does specifically just that, it reads to the end of the stream. I would check to make sure that you were actually being sent the entire expected response.