# System.Net.HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() returns truncated body in WebException

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

For some reason beyond my understanding requests made to a perticular website (https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/people/mrollins?view=profile) result in a reqsponse-object whose responsestream contain a trunkated version of the website.

The stream ends after 65536 bytes, which equals 2^16 bytes. I consider that a suspiciously round number. The requests complains of an internal server error, which I surpress, because I have already verified both that webbrowsers are able to make sense of this response, and that the full html is included in the response from the server. (using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))

I've found the problem previously documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865594/webexception-response-getresponsestream-limited-to-65536-characters), which is unsatisfactory for the simple reason that it ends on this note:

> "I guess I'll have to hope the error
>   doesn't exceed 65536 characters..."

Well it does.

Workarounds appreciated, or if anyone knows of an upcomming fix that is good too.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object senderHidden, EventArgs eHidden)
        {
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            //Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/people/mrollins?view=profile");
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            req.Accept = "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12";
            req.KeepAlive = true;

            HttpWebResponse resp = null;
            try
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                var r = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                var memstream = Read(r.GetResponseStream());
                var wrongLength = memstream.Length;
            }
        }

        public static MemoryStream Read(Stream stream)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                memStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            return memStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have included some comments about the code. It is as simple a program as I have been able to make, which still demonstrates the problem. To see the problem, place a breakpoint at the end of the catch clause, and observe that only 2^16 bytes have been read. (wronglength = 65536)

Answer (score 16):

HttpWebRequest has a static property that limits the length of web requests. this line of code, inserted before the request is made, solves the problem.

```
HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength = 1048576;
```