# Does GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd() read only 182955 characters

Tags: c#, http

I am doing an HTTP POST and getting a huge XML back in the response . I am seeing that the xml gets truncated at 182956 th charcater and hence I am not able to Deserialize the response . Is there a way I can read the entire content ? Thanks in advance for your help .

```
string myresponse = string.Empty();
 HttpWebResponse httpmyResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myrequest.GetResponse();
 response = new StreamReader(httpmyResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Content-Length: 444313

Content-Type: application/xml

Comment: how much characters does the response have?

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918107/system-net-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream-returns-truncated-body-in-webexce) ?

Comment: I have updated the question . Content Length is 444313

Comment: @michaelmoore The question talks about the error response. I am seeing when Status code is 200, valid response

Comment: Content-Length is in bytes, you are counting characters.  The most obvious source of the problem is on the other end of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918107/system-net-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream-returns-truncated-body-in-webexce) I referred to [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856853/does-getresponsestream-readtoend-read-only-182955-characters#comment40491806_25856853) might actually solve your problem. In particular if you set `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` to bigger value it might help. Internally, here how `ResponseStream` is being created

```
   private Stream MakeMemoryStream(Stream stream) {
           // some code emitted here     
            SyncMemoryStream memoryStream = new SyncMemoryStream(0);      // buffered Stream to save off data
            try {
                //
                // Now drain the Stream
                //
                if (stream.CanRead) {
                    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesTransferred = 0;

                    int maxBytesToBuffer = (HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength == -1)?buffer.Length:HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength*1024;
                    while ((bytesTransferred = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length, maxBytesToBuffer))) > 0)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesTransferred);
                        if(HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength != -1)
                            maxBytesToBuffer -= bytesTransferred;
                    }
                }
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
            }
            catch {
            }

            // some other code

            return memoryStream;
        }
```

Important members here are `stream` that is response stream, and `memoryStream` - that is response stream that you're going to get back as a result to a method call `GetResposneStream()`. As you can see, before reading stream, method sets `maxBytesToBuffer` equal to `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength*1024`, if `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` is not equal to -1, otherwise to the length of `buffer` which is `1024`. Then, in the `while` loop, it reads stream, and on each iteration decreases `maxBytesToBuffer` by amount of bytes read (`maxBytesToBuffer -= bytesTransferred`). 
Now lets consider both cases

1. `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` is `-1`, `stream` length is `444313`. In this case `maxBytesToBuffer` will be equal to `buffer.Length`, which is `1024`. So it will read `1024` bytes, as a result `bytesTransferred` will be `1024`, after first iteration, `maxBytesToBuffer` will become 0 (because of `maxBytesToBuffer -= bytesTransferred`), so next time it will read `0` bytes, and exit `while` loop, so you will have only `1024` bytes read from your entire stream.
2. `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` is `1024`, `stream` length is `444313`. In this case `maxBytesToBuffer` will be equal to  `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength*1024 = 1048576`. Again entering `while` loop first time, it will read `1024` (because of `Math.Min(buffer.Length, maxBytesToBuffer)`). On each iteration it will decrease `maxBytesToBuffer` by `1024`, so while loop can iterate at least `1024` times, each time reading `1024` bytes. After roughly `433` iterations (that is your content length `444313/1024 = 433.8`) it should read all of your content in the stream.

Having said this, I would first check what's the value of `DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength` and do the math (as I've done previously), and see if that is root cause of your problem or not.

Code was taken from [MS Reference Source web site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs)